# Parallel linear algebra without OpenMP

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, parallel-computing, linear-solver

I have searched through the archives without success. Apparently, the question is simple:

What linear algebra library can I use that is parallel (shared memory) but **without** OpenMP?

As far as I've seen, OpenMP seems a requirement. Since I need to interact with colleagues using a Mac, I cannot opt for OpenMP (no, I cannot ask them to compile gcc). The usage would be a classic FEM, so matrices, vectors, and decompositions (or some kind of parallel linear solver).

Intel's TBB is ok, of course, pthreads are good, standard C++ `std::thread` would be the perfection. But I'm not looking for perfection :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is the threading in the apple BLAS implementation sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: As far as I remember it doesn't have solvers.

Comment: As I recall, you get the usual LAPACK suite, so basically LU.

Comment: Recent versions of clang ([3.8.0](http://openmp.llvm.org/)) do support OpenMP, but I don't think they've made it into Xcode yet, so at least there is *some* way to get OpenMP on osx without installing gcc.

Comment: How large are the FE problems you are planning to solve? As you may already know, for large models, the decomposition of the global matrix tends to dominate the computational cost.

Comment: @origimbo I've found some examples of `Accelerate` framework but they seem to be single threaded; maybe I need even larger examples (I have a `10x10`), but I cannot find any. @Bill I need to solve 100K-400K DOFs, more if I can afford to do so.

Comment: Why you cant' ask them to compile GCC? With MacPorts: `sudo port install ggc49`

Comment: The sad story is that I would end up doing that myself. I want to pass them the code, not administering other machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the relatively large problems you are targeting, I suggest
you focus on the sparse matrix solver because that's where you'll
get the biggest benefit from parallelism.

From the comments it wasn't clear if you had access to a high-quality
multi-threaded BLAS library on all your target platforms.

If you do, and are also able to compile FORTRAN code, the MUMPS solver
is in my opinion the best free sparse solver for FE applications.

http://mumps.enseeiht.fr/

It is actually designed for distributed memory parallelism (MPI) but it does
an amazingly-good job with just a multi-threaded BLAS on multicore
machines. It also has an out-of-core option which is very useful for
solving large problems on desktop machines with limited memory.

A second option is SPOOLES.

http://www.netlib.org/linalg/spooles/spooles.2.2.html

It is an older sparse solver, not quite at the state of the art,
but it can be built with pthreads and it is written entirely in C.

Finally, a third option is PaStiX.

http://pastix.gforge.inria.fr/files/README-txt.html

I haven't actually tried it, myself, so can't comment further except
to say that it, too, supports pthreads.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill. Do you have any pointers for "pseudo-sparse" matrices, aka, banded, triangular, symmetric, ..., the standard ones used also in LAPACK. Not managing memory layout would be definitely a plus.

Comment: General sparse solvers have largely replaced banded and even variable-band (profile) solvers for all but academic FE applications. So I would not recommend going in that direction.